# Error while sending email on GoDaddy Server: Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

**I am using inbuilt template of Login System in Laravel 5.1**

When I use Forgot Password on localhost, everything works. Below are my keys in .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=userid
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

When I try the same thing on Godaddy server, I am facing the below error.

> Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 265: Connection
> could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection refused
>
> ## 111]

Comment: most likely the port 587 is blocked on your server.

Comment: I tried with 465, still same issue.

Comment: can you ssh to the server? or you can scan the open ports with http://mxtoolbox.com/PortScan.aspx

Comment: I got this after scan. http://prntscr.com/9hcqmj   Please check the screenshot in the url.

Comment: you did the wrong protocol scan, here is an example http://prntscr.com/9hcudb

Comment: When I open the page : mxtoolbox.com/PortScan.aspx  it given me a textbox to type me my domain name and then i press submit to scan port. this gives me results as shown here :  prntscr.com/9hcqmj

Comment: Have you adjusted your gmail settings to accept less secure apps? https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: This might help you.

http://laravel.io/forum/04-13-2014-setting-up-godaddy-as-smtp-server-get-501-helo-requires-valid-address-half-the-time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Your env file must be like below**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

In your `config/mail.php`, the from value should be like below...

```
'from' => ['address' => 'pankaj@YourDomainName.com', 'name' => 'Sender Name'],
```

**What's your domain Name in from ? or you can say, How to create Email account in GoDaddy ?**

> 1. Login in your GoDaddy Account
> 2. Go to your Hosting Account.
> 3. Click Manage
> 4. Under Email category, Please click Accounts
> 5. Create an account if there is no email account.

and that's it.

So let's say you have email address like Pankaj@yourdomainname.com

Now, put this email address in config/mail.php for from field. That's it.

This will 100% fix the issue

Comment: I am getting : Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 268:
Connection could not be established with host localhost [ #0]
in StreamBuffer.php line 268

Comment: If you have configured email with cpanel email account then go to cpanel and get domain name from URL @SadafSiddiqui

Comment: This solution is working,Thanks alot....I was surprised that the solution to the problem was this simple.. Thanks alot once more

Answer (score 3):

I had a hell of a time trying to find an answer to this so hopefully this helps someone. I was able to relay using my GoDaddy email account settings for a while but for whatever reason that stopped working. I'm now using the standard PHP Mail function to send emails and here's the .env config for that. Not sure if port or encryption are necessary but it's working so left it as is.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking around web, it seems when using GoDaddy you need to use their relay SMTP with Gmail credentials when you want to send an e-mail.

So in your `.env` file instead of:

```
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
```

you should use

```
MAIL_HOST=here_godaddy_relay_server
```

The exact value of relay server depends on hosting you have but it will be probably `relay-hosting.secureserver.net` so try first with:

```
MAIL_HOST=relay-hosting.secureserver.net
```

Further details: https://www.godaddy.com/help/what-is-the-name-of-my-hosting-accounts-relay-server-953+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: @Helper Godaddy uses strange mechanism depending on country, Use Google.com (COM not another), paste `godaddy Managing Your Email Account SMTP Relays` to searchbar and if you click on it and it redirects you, go back to google and try to display Cached Google Copy of this page

Comment: do you have godaddy account ? if so, can you give step by step guidelines like it was done in your previous bounty answer ?

Comment: Nope, sorry, I don't have, but I think it should work out of the box if you change `MAIL_HOST` in `.env` file

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i keep getting this `Connection could not be established with host relay-hosting.secureserver.net [Connection refused #111]`

Answer (score 1):

For my shared hosting at goDaddy

I could configure my .env with the values from cPanel->Email Wizard->Configure Mail Client

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Config email to your Laravel project first, create an email account in the host and check config details.
[image]

Now config you `.env` file example:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=mail.22h.in
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

And your `config/mail.php` Should be like this.

```
'from' => ['address' => 'demo@domain.in', 'name' => 'Order Receipt'],
```

Clear your project cache and config , Run these command

```
php artisan config:Cache
php artisan cache:Clear
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons could be **wrong Mail_RRIVER** etc in the **.env file**. Please make sure you put the right information there, e. g. for **GMAIL** the following input will work!

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=**<YOUR_USER_NAME>**@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=**<YOUR_PASSWORD>**
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update for Laravel 7 and up**

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```