# Issue in Laravel 5.1 Inner Join Query

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

**Below is my Query in Laravel 5.1**

```
\App\Models\Project\Bids\ProjectBid_Model
::selectRaw('B.*')
->join('tblproject P','B.projectid','=','P.projectid')
->where('P.WhoCreatedTheProject',14)
->first()
```

**and below is the equivalant query**

```
select B.* from `tblprojectbid` 
inner join `tblproject P` on `B`.`projectid` = `P`.`projectid` 
where `P`.`WhoCreatedTheProject` = 14 limit 1
```

### **What's the problem ?**

Please check the line 1 in Query: `select B.* from tblprojectbid`.

### **What's the question ?**

How can I change

`select B.* from tblprojectbid`

to

`select B.* from  tblprojectbid B`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Eloquent I'm afraid there is no easy way to do it.

I use in this case full table name for model for instance

```
\App\Models\Project\Bids\ProjectBid_Model
::selectRaw('bid_table.*')
->join('tblproject AS P','bid_table.projectid','=','P.projectid')
->where('P.WhoCreatedTheProject',14)
->first()
```

However it's also possible that you set alias in `ProjectBid_Model`:

```
protected $table = 'bid_table AS B';
```

The con is you will have this table always aliased with `B`, so in case you have 2 models with same alias (in this case `B`), you won't be able to change it later just for one table, so I think the better is 1st approach (without using alias)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34423189/error-while-sending-email-on-godaddy-server-laravel-5-1

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the final solution.**

```
\App\Models\Project\Bids\ProjectBid_Model
    ::selectRaw('B.*')
    ->from('tblprojectbid as B')
    ->join('tblproject as P','B.projectid','=','P.projectid')
    ->where('P.WhoCreatedTheProject',14)
    ->first()
```

Comment: I need to verify it in my applications. I haven't used `from` when using Eloquent.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
\DB::table('tblprojectbid as B')
->select()
->join('tblproject as P','B.projectid','=','P.projectid')
->where('P.WhoCreatedTheProject',14)
->first()
```

Comment: can u change it using `Model` as I have to use `with` statement also in the query.