# Error Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 This is a submission only port. You must authenticate before sending mail

Tags: laravel, centos, smtp, swiftmailer

I have the centos server with laravel setup. I am facing issue while sending email from server. My laravel version is 5.8.29 and PHP version is 7.3.6. I am using SMTP to send email. Guys please do help me out. Here are my code.

It's very strange to say that from my local setup from my system I am able to send email with same SMTP details with current project setup with same code. But some how on production server the emails are not sending. I have cross checked with swift mailer and tested with separate file for only email send  and its work. But from actual environment is not work.

.env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.domain.com
MAIL_PORT=587
mail_username=username
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Email should be send from the environment file

Comment: try php artisan config:clear after editing .env value
and try change mail port to 465, 25 or 2525

Comment: @GhiffariAssamar Thanks It fixed now. I came to know after so much debug that the credential details are not loading from .env file.  It's fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to send an e-mail via Gmail then you need to verify your Gmail account with 2 step verification and generate mail password. for verifying your Gmail account to throw this link [enter link description here](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/) after verifying your account go to "security->app password" generate mail password. select app "mail" and select device "window computer" copy the generated password paste into your `.env` file

Your `.env` file show look like:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=username
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

After saving your`.env` file, remove project config and cache with the command

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```

For sending an email via Domain follow this link [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34467165/8996394)

Comment: Its fixed now as mention in above comment the credential was not loading from .env file. I have fixed that. And it's working now.

Comment: Great @JigneshMistry